# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextUnit_Character'

Tags: python, eclipse

i get an error for  the following code in Automa

```
>>>start("notepad")
Application('Untitled_Notepad')
>>>click("File", "Save")
```

**Error**

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextUnit_Character'
```

Comment: Even I am getting the same bro...!!!

Answer (score 0):

The tool is compatible with Windows 7 & above. You might be trying on Windows xp.

So give a try on W7 & let me know.